# Parsing JSON logs from servers using Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, rest

From the below logs in JSON, I need to parse log lines of "domains" which have "ADMIN_DOWN" status and it didn't change or changed to "ONLINE" from 7 days.

Example:

Last line from logs shared below:

```
{user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-15 12:16:40.655569+00","id”:3201,”message”:”sub1.a1.com" new status = ADMIN_DOWN [asda:sdadada]”},
```

There is a domain: ”sub1.a1.com" in message key and status went "ADMIN_DOWN" but it comes to "ONLINE" in 3rd line of logs. so, we can ignore this as this domain already came "ONLINE".

I have to get all log lines which have "ADMIN_DOWN" from past 7 days and same domains have no logs generated with "ONLINE" later.

There is also a "id" which is always incrementing with time. Not sure if need to use it.

I started with the below code but not sure how to compare these log timestamps with past 7 days with current date. I just added a comment in second last line of code but need to add logic instead.

I am thinking if I can convert both timers (current and log timers) to convert in epoch. How to proceed to with code now.

I will appreciate any help.

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
    import json 

    with open('file.json') as data_file:  
        data = json.load(data_file)
    for i in data[‘dump’]:
        if 'ADMIN_DOWN' in i['message'] and <older than 7 days from current timestamp with same hostname>:
            print “those log line”
```

**JSON LOGS:**

```
 {“dump”:[
    { user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-24 12:52:40.655569+00","id”:4354,”message”:”sub1.google.com new status = ONLINE [asda:sdadada]”},
    {user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-23 14:38:40.274873+00","id”:4200,”message”:”sub1.adsense.com new status = ADMIN_DOWN [asda:sdadada]”},
    {user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-23 12:16:40.652369+00","id”:4155,”message”:”sub1.a1.com new status = ONLINE [asda:sdadada]”},
    {user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-22 16:46:40.598569+00","id”:4110,”message”:”sub1.b1.com new status = ADMIN_DOWN [asda:sdadada]”},
    {user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-18 12:55:40.132569+00","id”:3599,”message”:”sub1.google.com new status = ONLINE [asda:sdadada]”},
    {user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-15 13:09:40.655569+00","id”:3598,”message”:”sub1.bbc.com new status = ADMIN_DOWN [asda:sdadada]”},
    { user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-24 12:16:40.655569+00","id”:3555,”message”:”sub1.b1.com new status = ONLINE [asda:sdadada]”},
    {user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-23 11:06:40.655569+00","id”:3544,”message”:”sub1.d1.com new status = ADMIN_DOWN [asda:sdadada]”},
    {user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-23 12:19:40.655569+00","id”:3414,”message”:”sub1.c1.com new status = ADMIN_DOWN [asda:sdadada]”},
    {user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-22 09:16:40.655569+00","id”:3311,”message”:”sub1.google.com new status = ONLINE [asda:sdadada]”},
    {user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-18 12:46:40.655569+00","id”:3303,”message”:”sub1.b1.com new status = ADMIN_DOWN [asda:sdadada]”},
    {user=abc,”lastUpdated":"2017-10-15 12:16:40.655569+00","id”:3201,”message”:”sub1.a1.com new status = ADMIN_DOWN [asda:sdadada]”},
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date
TODAY = date(2017,10,25)
#Here data is the json
for i in data["dump"]:
    if "ADMIN_DOWN" in i["message"]:
        d = i["lastUpdated"].split()[0].split("-")
        DOWN_DATE = date(int(d[0]),int(d[1]),int(d[2]))
        if (TODAY - DOWN_DATE).days >= 7:
            print i
```